# Getting Values of Specific Elements of a data frame in R

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, r-factor

I have a very simple code, I do not understand why not working the way I want. Basically, I have a data frame and want to capture the value of n'th element of a column in the data frame, and store it in a vector. Here is my code:

```
COL1_VALUES <- c("ABC","XYZ","PQR")
COL2_VALUES <- c("DEF","JKL","TSM")

means <- data.frame(COL1_VALUES,COL2_VALUES)

for (i in 1:nrow(means)) {
    COL1_VALUES[i] <- means$COL1[i];
    COL2_VALUES[i] <- means$COL2[i];
}

print(means$COL1)
print(COL1_VALUES)
```

This outputs:

```
[1] ABC XYZ PQR
Levels: ABC PQR XYZ
[1] "1" "3" "2"
```

Why not am I not getting ABC XYZ TSM in the vector COL1_VALUES? It appears like 1, 3, 2 are the indices of ABC XYZ TSM in means$COL1. What do I need to get ABC XYZ TSM in the vector COL1_VALUES?

Thanks.

Comment: `COL1_VALUES` as a vector is a `character` vector. When it is put into a `data.frame()` it gets converted to a `factor` (since `data.frame(...,stringsAsFactors=TRUE)` by default). I think this explains your difference.

Comment: I don't understand why are you doing this in the first place. Your code does practiacally nothing usefull

Comment: @DavidArenburg this is 100 times simplified version of my actual code to provide an example case here.

Comment: @Baykal your `means$COL1` was converted to a factor. (Factor is basically an integer with a text label). Try: `means <- data.frame(COL1_VALUES,COL2_VALUES, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

Comment: Terry Therneau, longtime S/R user and survival package author, says his R shop has mandated `options(stringsAsFactors =FALSE)` as part of their `.Rprofile.site`.

Comment: @akhmed that worked. Thanks a lot. Why don't you convert that to an answer and I can mark it.

Comment: I agree -- this question does deserve a full answer especially if it is rephrased into a more general one/easily searchable. (For example, "Why is character vector displayed as  integers when added to a data.frame?" or so). `stringsAsFactors=TRUE` can be a huge source of confusion for beginners and affects other functions as well (see my answer).

Comment: @Baykal actually that answer was provided by thelatemail in his first comment, not sure what was so special about akhmeds comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R, `data.frame()` function ships with a default setting of `stringsAsFactors=TRUE`. This means that all input character vectors are implicitly converted into so called "factors" when creating a data.frame.

*factor* is somewhat like a vector with integers + a text labels that describe those integers. For example, if column `gender` has a type `factor` it is actually a vector of integers with `1`s and `2`s plus an attached dictionary that category id `1` means `Male` and category id `2` means `Female` or vice versa.

This default setting on `stringsAsFactors` is a sneaky beast and can show up in numerous unexpected locations. In most of these cases, it helps just to add an explicit `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` option so as to keep character vectors as character vectors.

Below I list the functions that I personally struggled with until realising that all I am missing is `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` option:

- `data.frame`
- `read.csv`, `read.table` and other `read.*` functions
- `expand.grid`

In your specific example above, what you need to do is find this line:

```
means <- data.frame(COL1_VALUES,COL2_VALUES)
```

and replace it with:

```
means <- data.frame(COL1_VALUES,COL2_VALUES,
                     stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

such that you are explicitly requesting `data.frame()` not to do any implicit conversions behind your back.

You can also avoid this conversion by changing the global option at the beginning of each R session:

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Note, however, that modifying this global option only affects your machine and snippets of your code may stop working on the machines of others.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177921/how-to-disable-stringsasfactors-true-in-data-frame-permanently/8177936#8177936) contains more information about how to disable it permanently.