# Compare two columns element-wise

Tags: r, string, match, sapply

I have a big dataset `df` (354903 rows) with two columns named `df$ColumnName` and `df$ColumnName.1`

```
head(df)
       CompleteName       CompleteName.1
1   Lefebvre Arnaud Lefebvre Schuhl Anne
1.1 Lefebvre Arnaud              Abe Lyu
1.2 Lefebvre Arnaud              Abe Lyu
1.3 Lefebvre Arnaud       Louvet Nicolas
1.4 Lefebvre Arnaud   Muller Jean Michel
1.5 Lefebvre Arnaud  De Dinechin Florent
```

I am trying to create labels to see whether the name is the same or not.
When I try a small subset it works [1 if they are the same, 0 if not]:

```
> match(df$CompleteName[1], df$CompleteName.1[1], nomatch = 0)
[1] 0
> match(df$CompleteName[1:10], df$CompleteName.1[1:10], nomatch = 0)
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

But as soon as I throw the complete columns, it gives me complete different values, which seem nonsense to me:

```
> match(df$CompleteName, df$CompleteName.1, nomatch = 0)
[1] 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101
[23] 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101
[45] 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101
```

Should I use `sapply`? I did not figured it out, I tried this with an error:

```
 sapply(df, function(x) match(x$CompleteName, x$CompleteName.1, nomatch = 0))
```

Please help!!!

Comment: you probably don't want match - it gives the matching values form the second column, not whether they are equal. If you have strings, you could probable just use `as.numeric(df$CompleteName == df$CompleteName.1)`

Comment: also, use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in constructing your data.frame

Comment: @thelatemail as others have pointed out, `match` won't work here. my comment was meant to add to @jeremycg 's

Comment: There is also no evidence of these being factor columns anyway, is there?

Comment: @thelatemail: No, it doesn't work if there are other levels. See my answer and try to run it without stringsAsFactors = FALSE

Comment: @HaddE.Nuff `> default.stringsAsFactors()
[1] TRUE`

Comment: @jaimedash - That's not what I meant.  I mean that we have no idea whether this OP has factor columns or not.  There is no evidence in the question that tells us whether they are factor or character. It's not a big deal though.  This is one reason why `dput()` is preferred when posting data in a question.

Comment: Yes! Saul for future questions, try to follow these guidelines, which make answering easier http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/4598520 You could also edit your question to be reproducible

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the man page of match,

> ‘match’ returns a vector of the positions of (first) matches of
>   its first argument in its second.

So your data seem to indicate that the first match of "Lefebvre Arnaud" (the first position in the first argument) is in the row 101. I believe what you intended to do is a simple comparison, so that's just the equality operator `==`.

Some sample data:

```
> a <- rep ("Lefebvre Arnaud", 6)
> b <- c("Abe Lyu", "Abe Lyu", "Lefebvre Arnaud", rep("De Dinechin Florent", 3))
> x <- data.frame(a,b, stringsAsFactors=F)
> x
            a                   b
1 Lefebvre Arnaud             Abe Lyu
2 Lefebvre Arnaud             Abe Lyu
3 Lefebvre Arnaud     Lefebvre Arnaud
4 Lefebvre Arnaud De Dinechin Florent
5 Lefebvre Arnaud De Dinechin Florent
6 Lefebvre Arnaud De Dinechin Florent
> x$a == x$b
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

**EDIT:** Also, you need to make sure that you are comparing apples to apples, so double check the data type of your columns. Use `str(df)` to see whether the columns are strings or factors. You can either construct the matrix with "stringsAsFactors = FALSE", or convert from factor to character. There are several ways to do that, check here: [Convert data.frame columns from factors to characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851015/convert-data-frame-columns-from-factors-to-characters#2851213)

Answer (score 4):

As others have pointed out, `match` isn't right here. What you want is equality, which you can get by testing with `==`, which gives you `TRUE/FALSE`. Then using `as.numeric` will give you desired `1/0` or using `which` will give you the indices.

**But** you may still have an issue with factors!

```
 # making up some similar data( adapted from earlier answer)
 a <- rep ("Lefebvre Arnaud", 6)
 b <- c("Abe Lyu", "Abe Lyu", "Lefebvre Arnaud", rep("De Dinechin Florent", 3))
 df <- data.frame(CompleteName = a, CompleteName.1 = b)
 which(df$CompleteName == df$CompleteName1)
 #integer(0)
 #Warning message:
 #In is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'

 str(df)
 # 'data.frame':    6 obs. of  2 variables:
 # $ CompleteName  : Factor w/ 1 level "Lefebvre Arnaud": 1 1 1 1 1 1
 # $ CompleteName.1: Factor w/ 3 levels "Abe Lyu","De Dinechin Florent",..: 1 1 3 2 2 2
```

`stringsAsFactors`

Above, the data.frame wasn't constructed with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` and caused an error. Unfortunately, out of the box `R` will coerce strings to factors on loading a `csv` or creating a `data.frame`. This can be fixed when creating the data.frame by explicitly specifying `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`

```
df <- data.frame(CompleteName = a, CompleteName.1 = b, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df[which(df$CompleteName == df$CompleteName.1), ]
##     CompleteName CompleteName.1
## 3 Lefebvre Arnaud Lefebvre Arnaud
```

To avoid the issue in the future, run `options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` at the beginning of your R session (or put it at the top of your `.R` script). More discussion here:

- [disable stringsAsFactors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177921/how-to-disable-stringsasfactors-true-in-data-frame-permanently)

Comment: BEWARE that using non-standard "options" on your code may make it harder for you to write collaborative code! Whenever you send your script to other people, the different options may cause the script to break down.

Comment: +1 when collaborating on code it's better to put it at the beginning of a script file than in the  .Rprofile for this reason

Comment: @HaddE.Nuff good point. I just swapped the df to the one the other answer

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using a `data.table` with performance comparison to the `data.frame` solution based on an identical number of records as in your case.

```
col1 = sample(x = letters, size = 354903, replace = TRUE)
col2 = sample(x = letters, size = 354903, replace = TRUE)

library(data.table)
dt = data.table(col1 = col1, col2 = col2)
df = data.frame(col1 = col1, col2 = col2)

# comparing the 2 columns
system.time(dt$col1==dt$col2)
system.time(df$col1==df$col2)

# storing the comparison in the table/frame itself
system.time(dt[, col3:= (col1==col2)])
system.time({df$col3 = (df$col1 == df$col2)})
```

The `data.table` approach offers a significant speedup on my machine: from 0.020s to 0.008s.

Try it for yourself and see.  I know this is not really significant with such a small number of rows but multiply that 1000 and you'll see a major difference!

Comment: That's an interesting take on the problem, but it uses far more complex code than necessary. This is not a question about performance, and premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: I don't believe it's far more complex than necessary, typing `data.table` instead of `data.frame` is actually less typing and takes advantage of a considerably more efficient storage mechanism.  I'm glad I got into the practice of using this package at an early juncture, it's saved me a considerable amount of time and I'd encourage new R users to do likewise so that when the really need it they have the tools in place.

Comment: The problem I see in your answer is having to learn the `data.table` syntax. `col3:= ` is absolutely meaningless for someone who doesn't understand `data.table` syntax. It's a very elegant line, and far more efficient than some "pure R" code, but using it or not is a choice nonetheless.

Comment: I appreciate this answer, I will look deep into this `data.table`method. It definitely will help me if I get to reduce the operation time, normally I was dealing with 2 million rows dataset, and this was a combination of a subset of 800 records.
Thank you for the insight!!!