# Print matching words of two columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, multiple-columns, string-comparison, string-matching

I have 2 data frames that have usernames.

input1

```
username
akshay
bhanu
catherine
dennis
```

input2

```
username
akshay
bhanu
catherine
dennis
edward
francis
```

I have to find the matching words for 2 columns. Have around 120+ names on both columns, I just gave a few as an example. I tried a few ways but it says the length of data frames are different.

Comment: I don't really understand if you have two data frame or one data frame with two columns

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matching two Columns in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36345915/matching-two-columns-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filter function from the dplyr package.

```
input1 = filter(username %in% input2$username)
```